# Undefined is not a function when using jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a plugin that converts my select boxes to better looking select boxes through a method called tzSelect(), which is contained in the jquery.tzSelect.js file. When this file is called from script.js (it is called on document ready), it functions correctly. However, when called in main.js, I get Unknown TypeError: Undefined is not a function.

This is the functioning call in script.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('select.regularSelect').tzSelect();
});
```

This is the nonfunctioning call in main.js (not within anything else)

```
  function redoSelect(){
    $('select.regSelect').tzSelect();
  }
```

And lastly, the order in which my javascript is loaded in my footer:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/ready_script.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="/static/tzSelect/jquery.tzSelect.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/script.js"></script>
```

The plugin only works with the older jquery, which explains the version. I have tried placing the function in a document.ready and using the word jQuery instead of $, both to no avail. Any ideas?

EDIT: Fixed. The issue was with my jQuery version. The newer version of jQuery broke a couple of features, which I was then able to fix with small edits.

Comment: I think the plugin reference should be included above the main.js reference

Comment: thank you, but i have tried both ways and still get the same TypeError

Comment: where are you calling `redoSelect()` from?

Comment: i am calling it from a line in a different function, which is not within anything else. I also tried calling it from the js console and still get the same TypeError